# Monitoring the Java melody jdbc connections

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, java-melody

I have to monitor the jdbc connections using java melody in web application using the jdbc url and user name and parameter instead of JNDI.

Application is not using spring / hibernate.

I tried with passing the below system prameters using -D option.

```
-Dhibernate.connection.driver_class=net.bull.javamelody.JdbcDriver
-Dhibernate.connection.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
-Dhibernate.connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@db1:1521:gorcl
-Dhibernate.connection.username=staging
-Dhibernate.connection.password=stage123##
```

But it is not monitoring the sql.

Please let me know how to configure the sql monitoring using plain url, user name and password for oracle / tomcat web application.

Comment: If your application does not use hibernate, hibernate.connection.url will do nothing.
And if it does not use spring, hibernate or JNDI, you should share how do you open jdbc connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find the solution to monitor using url and user name and password.

I converted application to use jndi connection pool and able to monitor.